# Retrieving all pair shortest path of a dynamic graph efficiently

Tags: algorithm, optimization, graph, graph-algorithm, shortest-path

I'm studying shortest paths in directed graphs currently. There are many efficient algorithms for finding the shortest path in a network, like dijkstra's or bellman-ford's. But what if the graph is dynamic? By saying dynamic I mean that we can insert edges during the execution of program. I'm trying to find an efficient algorithm for updating the shortest paths from a vertex v to every other vertex u, after inserting an edge e, without needing to run the shortest path algorithm in the new graph again. How can I do this? I discussed with my professor the approach given in this question [Link](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/7250/retrieving-the-shortest-path-of-a-dynamic-graph?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). It initially runs floyd warshall on initial graph. Then when an edge is added between vertex u and vertex v, we do the following:
For every pair of nodes *x* and *y*,check if *d(x,u)+c(u,v)+d(v,y),  this can be done in *O(n^2)* since you are comparing every pair of nodes.  //d(x,y)* is the distance between vertex x and vertex y computed by Floyd Warshall algorithm initially.

My doubt is  that can we optimize above step so that we should not have to check for all pairs? Can we do better or not? If yes, what is the approach? And if no, what is the proof that we have to check for all pairs?

I draw some graphs and intuitively feels that we have to check for all pairs and we can't do better but still any proof will be helpful.

Comment: Maybe it's more appropriate in this section:https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I posted on it (https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/92115/retrieving-all-pair-shortest-path-of-a-dynamic-graph-efficiently) but didn't got any answer.

Comment: Well that's the right place for it, you can try all 130+ SE sites though looking for an answer...

Comment: it says on the link you gave that it is an open problem

Comment: It says that it is quite an difficult problem,not an open problem.